# Why does diff produce unexpected results for times when used with grouped tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `diff()` to find the time difference between consecutive observations on the same day using `dplyr`. If I calculate the difference between all observations (column t1) the units are consistent (in this case minutes). If I group by day (column t2) the units are hours for the first day, then minutes for the second. This results in a column in inconsistent units.

```
library(dplyr)

testdata <- data.frame(Day = structure(c(rep(11549:11550,c(5,15))), class = "Date"),
                       Time = structure(c(997878000, 997883400, 997897200, 997906500, 997913100, 
                                          997919400, 997924200, 997928700, 997934100, 997939200, 997944900, 
                                          997951500, 997957500, 997961700, 997965900, 997969500, 997972800, 
                                          997976100, 997981500, 997990500), 
                                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""))


testdata %>% mutate(t1 = c(NA, diff(Time)) )  %>%
  group_by(Day) %>% mutate(t2 = c(NA, diff(Time)) )

## A tibble: 20 x 4
## Groups:   Day [2]
#   Day        Time                   t1     t2
#   <date>     <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 13:20:00    NA  NA   
# 2 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 14:50:00    90   1.5 
# 3 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 18:40:00   230   3.83
# 4 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 21:15:00   155   2.58
# 5 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 23:05:00   110   1.83
# 6 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 00:50:00   105  NA   
# 7 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 02:10:00    80  80   
# 8 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 03:25:00    75  75   
# 9 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 04:55:00    90  90   
#10 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 06:20:00    85  85  
#...
```

The question is lined to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470389/diff-for-posixct-with-units-like-in-difftime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510044/how-to-make-time-difference-in-same-units-when-subtracting-posixct) question but seems sufficiently different to make a new question. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311747/3379675) avoids the problem by using `difftime` instead of `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `diff()` returns different units depending on the data it is provided with, although I can't see any documentation that indicates what criteria it uses for determining the units. If the function is called explicitly, the units are indicated, e.g.

```
diff(testdata$Time[1:5])
# Time differences in hours
# [1] 1.500000 3.833333 2.583333 1.833333
```

When the function is called from within `mutate` this output is suppressed, and the class `difftime` gets coerced silently to `numeric`. One way around this is to define a function that makes the conversion using an  explicit unit, e.g.

```
mydiff <- function(x){y <- diff(x); units(y) <- "mins"; y}

testdata %>% mutate(t1 = c(NA, mydiff(Time)) )  %>%
  group_by(Day) %>% mutate(t2 = c(NA, mydiff(Time)) )


# # A tibble: 20 x 4
# # Groups:   Day [2]
#   Day        Time                   t1    t2
#   <date>     <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 13:20:00    NA    NA
# 2 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 14:50:00    90    90
# 3 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 18:40:00   230   230
# 4 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 21:15:00   155   155
# 5 2001-08-15 2001-08-15 23:05:00   110   110
# 6 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 00:50:00   105    NA
# 7 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 02:10:00    80    80
# 8 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 03:25:00    75    75
# 9 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 04:55:00    90    90
#10 2001-08-16 2001-08-16 06:20:00    85    85
#...
```